# Angular JS, Timezone, Currency and Locale

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my custom web-based application, the user has the ability to set his/her own timezone, locale, currency and language (independent of the computer they are using).

Is there a way to set these parameters for Angular at the App level, so that I don't have to set it for each and every currency or datetime value within the page?

```
<!-- something like this: -->
<html ng-app="myApp" ng-currency-symbol="GBP" ng-locale="fr-FR" ng-timezone="-5">
  <body ng-controller="MyAppController">
      <div class="list-group">
         <div class="list-group-entry">{{MyApp.SubTotal | currency}}</div>
         <div class="list-group-entry">{{MyApp.Total | currency}}</div> 
         <!-- both would print the value like following:
            (e.g: 5,000.32) as £5 000,32 -->
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The objective is to keep the code the natural way developers write AngularJS, however be able to globally set currency symbol, locale and timezone of the user who is browsing the app.

Comment: Are you just trying to access all the user preferences across the app?

Comment: You could use a custom Angular service to keep track of the preferences, then call that from both the filter code and the addon code. Alternatively, you can use the global scope to store this, however that would be going against Angular idioms and design patterns.

Comment: Zeke, can you provide a sample code? I am having a hard time following you.

Answer (score 0):

Angular supports `i18n` Standard for location | globalization | internationalization.  When it comes to number formatting Angular relies on `$locale` servic. For example regarding number formatting this services uses the property `NUMBER_FORMATS` there it is defined the currency symbol by itself will not change the numbering formatting unless you change the 'location'.

Here is the list of locations currently supported by angular:

http://cdnjs.com/libraries/angular-i18n/

Here is an example on how to support [german locale](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n):

```
<html ng-app>
 <head>

   <script src="angular.js"></script>
   <script src="i18n/angular-locale_de-de.js"></script>

 </head>
</html>
```

If you want to dig more into it you can search for `NUMBER_FORMATS` in any of the CDNs provided above and you will find what angular will use to format your numbers, this is an example:

```
"NUMBER_FORMATS": {
    "CURRENCY_SYM": "\u20ac",
    "DECIMAL_SEP": ",",
    "GROUP_SEP": ".",
...
```